# Python Dataframe Merge for matching

Tags: python, pandas, merge, matching

I wish to make matching pairs from two dataframes such that no two pairs aree same and even the individual values also don't repeat in any other  pairs. The key to use in matching is 'cntr-size' and 'carrier'.

Eg:

```
import_v = pd.DataFrame({
    'cntr_no':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    'cntr_size':[40,40,20,40,40,20,20,20],
    'carrier': ['MSK', 'MSK', 'MSC','MSK', 'MSK', 'MSC','CMA', 'MSK']
})

export_v = pd.DataFrame({
    'cntr_no':[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
    'cntr_size':[40,40,20,40,40,20,20,20,40,40,20,20],
    'carrier': ['MSK', 'MSK', 'MSC','MSK', 'MSK', 'MSC','MSK', 'MSK','MSK', 'HLL','MSK', 'MSK']
})
```

if I merge with -

```
potential = pd.merge(import_v,export-v,on=['cntr_size','carrier'])
```

Output I'm getting -

```
[Out I Get][1]
cntr_no_x   cntr_size   carrier cntr_no_y
0   1   40  MSK 9
1   1   40  MSK 10
2   1   40  MSK 12
3   1   40  MSK 13
4   1   40  MSK 17
5   2   40  MSK 9
6   2   40  MSK 10
7   2   40  MSK 12
8   2   40  MSK 13
9   2   40  MSK 17
10  4   40  MSK 9
11  4   40  MSK 10 .... so on
12  4   40  MSK 12
13  4   40  MSK 13
14  4   40  MSK 17
```

Output I want -

```
cntr_no_x   cntr_size   carrier cntr_no_y
0   1   40  MSK 9
1   2   40  MSK 10
2   4   40  MSK 12
```

So `cntr_no_x` and `cntr_no_y` both should be unique and not repeat itself

Answer (score 0):

The solution came from -

```
cntr_list_i=[]
cntr_list_e=[]
match_scale['status']=""
for ind in match_scale.index:
    if (match_scale.loc[ind,'container_no_x']) not in cntr_list_i and (match_scale.loc[ind,'container_no_y']) not in cntr_list_e:
        match_scale.loc[ind,'status']=True
        cntr_list_i.append(match_scale.loc[ind,'container_no_x'])
        cntr_list_e.append(match_scale.loc[ind,'container_no_y'])
```